# Рисование диаграмм с помощью HighCharts js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Решил изучить js framework HighCharts. Создал проект asp.net mvc. Скачал с нагета библиотеку Highsoft.Highcharts версии 6.1.0.53. И добавил свою вьюху к стандартному макету mvc. Код view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Diagramm";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Столбиковая диаграмма'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Категория 1', 'Категория 2', 'Категория 3']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Ось значений'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Значение 1',
                data: [1, 5, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'Значение 2',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
```

Дописал контроллер:

```
public ActionResult Diagramm()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Добавил подключение библиотек на _Layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../build/PP.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../libs/hc/highcharts.src.js"></script>
```

И при запуске вылетает ошибка:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Пример нашёл на просторах интернета. JS только начал изучать. Подскажите пожалуйста что я сейчас делаю не так. Хочется для начала увидеть хотя бы простенькую диаграмму.
_Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../build/PP.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../libs/hc/highcharts.src.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Diagramm", "Diagramm", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Ошибка:

> jquery-3.3.1.js:3827 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13
>       at Object.a.error (highcharts.js:10)
>       at a.Chart.getContainer (highcharts.js:254)
>       at a.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.js:269)
>       at a.Chart. (highcharts.js:245)
>       at a.fireEvent (highcharts.js:31)
>       at a.Chart.init (highcharts.js:244)
>       at a.Chart.getArgs (highcharts.js:244)
>       at new a.Chart (highcharts.js:243)
>       at HTMLDocument. (Diagramm:51)
>       at mightThrow (jquery-3.3.1.js:3534)

Новые подключения:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery должен подключаться раньше, чем использоваться. Вероятно, следуя лучшим практикам, вы добавили теги `script` ниже, чем `RenderBody`, из-за чего `$(function() {...})` не может нормально отработать.

Попробуйте заменить на `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...})`
или же обернуть свои скрипты в [Razor-section](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor)

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<html>
...
<body>
@RenderBody()

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../build/PP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../libs/hc/highcharts.src.js">
@RenderSection("ScriptsBottom", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

MyView.cshtml:

```
...
@section ScriptsBottom {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            'use strict';
            ...
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: free-ze, добавил код моей страницы _Layout в вопрос. Взгляните пожалуйста, что у меня там не так из того что вы имели в виду.

Comment: @Андрей, да, об этом и говорил. Представьте, что текст вашей вьюшки подставляется точно вместо `RenderBody` лейаута. У вас вызов `$` (jquery, хотя с остальными библиотеками та же история) оказывается *выше*, чем его определение. Как я и показал, у вас там ниже есть секция `scripts`, но на вьюшке вы ее не использовали. Попробуйте, я дополнил ответ примером того, как это сделать.

Comment: free_ze я попробовал немного подругому, просто расположил вызов jquery выше чем renderbody. И заменил подключения к framework'у потому что оказалось что эти не правильные, но всё равно вылетает ошибка. Добавляю её в ввопрос и новые подключения.

Comment: @Андрей, помимо jquery там остальные библиотеки будут иметь ту же проблему. Тяжелые файлы лучше все же загружать после тела страницы, иначе вы не увидите ничего до окончания их обработки. Секции - это достаточно распространенная практика в ASP.NET-мирке.

Comment: @Андрей, судя по коду, у вас jquery дважды подключается.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, спасибо за помощь.